# Replace a dot with a comma inside a jQuery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

U have a very simple jQuery template where I say the following:

```
<dt>${Math.round(ShippingCost*100)/100} kr.</dt>
```

However, that results in a value such as 200.00 kr.

Now I want to replace my dot with a comma, which I do like this:

```
<dt>${(Math.round(ShippingCost*100)/100).replace(".",",")} kr.</dt>
```

Which then results in:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `(Math.round(ShippingCost*100)/100).toString().replace(".",",")`

Comment: @dfsq results in same error, unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your expression inside `${}` into parentheses:

```
${((Math.round(ShippingCost*100)/100).toString().replace(".",","))}
```

Looks like something confuses template engine without it.

Another thing you need to fix is that you have to cast result of `Math.round` to string type, since `replace` is a method of String, not number. You can use simple `toString()` for this.